# Container without port mapping is accessible

Tags: docker, network-programming, traefik

I have a small setup with `traefik:v2.10-5` and `pgadmin:7.8` in `docker-compose` and a custom subnet.

- Subnet: `172.18.0.0/16`, gateway: `172.18.0.1`
- Traefik is at the fixed ipv4 `172.18.0.2`, with an entrypoint for pgadmin: `--entrypoints.pgadmin.address=:3744`
- Pgadmin is at the fixed ipv4 `172.18.0.3` and controlled by traefik with these labels:

```
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pgadmin-route.entrypoints=pgadmin"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pgadmin-route.rule=Host(`pgadmin.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.pgadmin-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

My `/etc/hosts` are extended so both traefik.com and pgadmin.com are mapped to traefik's IP (`172.18.0.2`). If traefik is on, http://pgadmin.com:3744 redirects me properly to the pgadmin service. When traefik is off, pgadmin is not reachable. So far so good.

However, I can reach pgadmin perfectly by going to http://172.18.0.3 **even without port forwarding** in my `yml`. How come I can do this? I thought that the whole point of docker is isolation, so I should **not** be able to be redirected anywhere. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're not missing anything. That's how it works.

Comment: Ah, great. Then I think I'm not understanding when would I need port forwarding? Besides the case where two services with the same IP want to listen at the same port.

Comment: You need port forwarding if you want your service to be reachable from outside the host machine. Also, the fact that you can use the bridge network IP address to reach the container is implementation dependent. I don't think it works on a Windows with WSL2 host for example.

Comment: Ahhh now I see! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'd suggest the standard approach is to assign `ports:` to the container(s) you want to have accessible from outside Docker, and completely ignore the container-internal IP addresses.  It sounds like you have a complex networking setup, but practically you can probably delete all of the `networks:` blocks in your Compose file.  As @HansKilian notes you can't use the container-private IP addresses in many common environments and you almost never need to specify them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Since I only need traefik to be accessible from the outside (as reverse-proxy / load balancer) I rethought the architecture and I could perfectly skip the networks section, since the docker service would re-route internally all traffic updating the IP routes. My main issue is that I need traefik to be at a fixed IP and I thought I need a subnet for that. Is there any other way to achieve this?